# Painting designs onto object

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to create a 3D textured model of a boomerang based on this image[image]

I have a good model and have applied a wood texture to it, but I'm pretty stumped when it comes to creating the designs in a way that looks convincing. If anyone knows a good way to approach this the help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my model so far:

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material

Answer (score 1):

Create the designs in photoshop or whatever image editing program you use. Export them with alpha.

In your material node, add a new image texture and mix it with your regular wood texture. Go to texture paint mode and load your art from photoshop as a texture for the brush. Set the brush mapping to Stencil and orient your view appropriately.

Here's a tutorial on how stenciling works in Blender: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnfTSXWF21A